# problem in launching a camera

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everybody!
I have installed the openni_kinect(the camera I use is kinect), then I entered "rosmake openni_kinect --rosdep-install" and "roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch" in the terminal, the first command got executed successfully, but the second one failed.
Here is some information in the terminal.

[rospack] warning: error parsing manifest file at [/home/llq/ros_workspace/pkgs/foobar/manifest.xml]?

Calibration hasn't been done to the camera, is this the cause? If so, is their any tutorial I can follow to complete the calibration?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11310/problem-in-launching-a-camera/) by [llqazs](https://answers.ros.org/users/1121/llqazs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has nothing to do with kinect. You have problem with the syntax in the manifest file of one of your personal packages (in /home/llq/ros_workspace/pkgs/foobar/). Resolve that first. Quick fix would be to move it out of your $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, so ros doesn't find it.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1